# Bootstrap multiline button groups

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three bootstrap button groups with 3 buttons each. I would like them to come below each other so that it becomes a grid of size 3 X 3. Also there should not be any space between two button rows. What's the best way to do it.

```
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-rotate-315"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-rotate-45"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-rotate-45"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-rotate-315"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there any problem you came across with just regular bootstrap columns and rows ? You can define 3 <div class="row> s and create 3 equally divided columns for each row <div class="col-md-4>s and place each button in these columns. And you should be able to get rid of the spacing with margin-top property. This should work or am I missing something in the question ? if so, please provide a jsfiddle so we can visualize the problem.

Comment: @sinanspd the buttons are floating on top of a canvas element. I tried aligning 3 btn-groups one below the other with no space between them. I tried setting margin-top and margin-bottom property to 0px. But that didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the full code or at least an html output screenshot if you havent solved the problem yet. We might be able to push down the rows all together to get them out of the canvas's way.  it might be a problem with how the canvas is rendered rather than how the buttons are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table;` to the `btn-group` class. may be it will work.

```
.btn-group{
     display: table;
}
```